# Trying to find a story about an old spaceship mechanic whose hand changes into different tools

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember a comic strip or cartoon about some space hero. The only thing I can remember about it is that he has a side kick who is an old man whose hand can change in to different tools to fix/repair the hero's space ship.

There's also some strange back story to the old man. I think he was a space marine engineer who have their hands cut off and replace with technology to morph in to different tools to help them complete their tasks.

The language was English (maybe dubbed) and it must of been > 10 years ago. I think the hero flies his space craft from one adventure to another, and there are some bad guys who our hero always stays one step ahead. The space ships are quite large (eg similar size of a small super tanker)

I remember in one scene the old guy is sitting on some large tubing/support inside the spaceship holding a cigar which he lights by changing his hand in to a blow touch.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you read it?  What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: Are you thinking of "Toolie" from Lifepod? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifepod

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortunately it's not Lifepod. I'm 100% sure it wasn't live actors, and I've added some more detail to my description.

Comment: It sounds like John Silver from Treasure Planet, but I'm not sure that's actually the case.

Comment: Hi, that was a good film, and he does have a maniacal arm, but my guy's hand just morphs in to tools, rather than transforms in to tools (if you understand my difference!!). But thank you for helping.